# $_SESSION variable selectively loading

Tags: php, javascript, session

So, this is a headscratcher.  I am submitting a login form via ajax, which is working properly.  On login I am setting several $_SESSION variables and loading 3 php files into divs to refresh the data using the user's account info.  Here is the javascript:

```
function processLogin() {
    $.post("/login/index.php" , $("#djloginform").serialize(), 
        function(data) {
            if (data.error == 0) {
                $("#featuredJobs").load("/jobs/featured.php");
                $("#allJobs").load("/jobs/alljobs.php");
                $("#loginbox").load("/login/loggedin-yes.php");
            }
            else {
                alert(data.error);
                $("#djloginemail").val("").focus();
                $("#djloginpassword").val("");
            }
        }, 'json');
}
```

featured.php and alljobs.php is loading correctly and using the $_SESSION variables, so they are being set correctly and used by 2 out of the 3 php files.  Here is the code for what isn't showing:

```
Logged in as 
<span style="font-weight: bold;">
    <?php echo $_SESSION['djfullname']; ?>
</span>
```

I just get "Logged in as", but when I refresh the page I get "Logged in as [name]".

The three pages are all using the same exact $_SESSION variables, so I don't know what's going on here.  Any ideas?

Comment: I know you said they're all using session variables but is `$_SESSION['djfullname'];` being used in more than one of the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use session_start(); before echoing $_SESSION['djfullname'].

Comment: Thanks--I'm an idiot.  I have session_start() in a php file with my sql info I'm including in every file but this one...thanks.